# ASP.Net Core Web API единый формат ответов

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.0-webapi

Собственно вопрос в тайтле.
Что я хочу: единый формат ответов от API как у VK.
Для успешных результатов примерно такой формат ответов:

```
{
    "response": {
        "count": 2,
        "items": [
            1,
            2,
        ]
    }
}
```

А для ошибок примерно такой формат:

```
{
    "error": {
        "error_code": 5,
        "error_msg": "User authorization failed: invalid access_token (4)."
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы ответы формировались сами (чтобы я из контроллера, например, возвращал IEnumerable, а ответ был как выше в примере), а не через контроллер и возвращаемый тип у методов (public MyResponse<> Foo()).

Comment: возможно можно сделать через IResultFilter, который будет оборачивать ответ

Answer (score 1):

Для обработки ошибок поможет middleware, который будет перехватывать все исключения и формировать ответ в едином виде:

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(nameof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext ctx)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next.Invoke(ctx);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(ctx, ex);
        }
    }
    
    private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        _logger.LogError(exception, exception.Message);
        var errorCode = "0"; //Получаете в зависимости от типа Exception
        var statusCode = 400;
        var message = exception.Message;

        context.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        await context.Response.WriteAsync( ErrorResponse.Build(errorCode, message));
    }
}


public class ErrorResponse
{
    public static string Build(string code, string message)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder("{");
        builder.AppendLine();
        builder.AppendLine("    \"error\": {");
        builder.AppendLine();
        builder.AppendFormat("        \"code\": \"{0}\",", code);
        builder.AppendLine();
        builder.AppendFormat("        \"message\": \"{0}\",", message);
        builder.AppendLine("    }");
        builder.AppendLine("}");
        
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

А вот с общим ответом не все так очевидно!
Пару вопросов на тему:
Будут ли ответы не содержащие коллекции? Будет ли свойство count вычисляться на основе количества элементов, либо же потребуется кастомные значения.

По опыту могу сказать, что использование таких обобщенных ответов не всегда является гибким!

Могу предложить использовать базовый класс для таких ответов:

```
public abstract class BaseResponse<T>
{
    protected BaseResponse(params T[] items)
    {
        Items = items;
        Count = items?.Length ?? 0;
    }

    public int Count { get; }
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; }
}
```

Comment: Пример ответа не обязательно будет содержать только коллекции. Создавать JSON объект строками?) Это как-то из каменного века

Comment: Это не из каменного века, это быстро! Нет накладных расходов на сериализация. Прикрутить сериализатор, дело двух строк. Это пример из реального проекта, в котором не три реквеста в час. Пример не без изъянов, но только в части того, что он не учитывает заголовок запроса Accept и всегда возвращает только json. Универсальное решение должно возвращать контент опираясь на его значение.